# GCP Data Fusion HTTP post-run plugin errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

from CDAP documentation exists an HTTPS post-run plugin to trigger pipeline start based on the successful execution of another pipeline ([Scheduling](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/en/developer-manual/pipelines/creating-pipelines.html#H3406)). I'm trying to use this functionality in GCP Data Fusion but the plugin even if installed (because I can see it from Control Center) seems to be not available.

I also tried to install manually the plugin [HTTP Plugin](https://github.com/cdapio/hydrator-plugins/blob/release/2.3/http-plugins/docs/HTTPCallback-postaction.md) v2.2.0 as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/plugins)  but has only sink and source action. Also if I try to use the plugin an error is displayed

> HTTP Properties 1.2.0 (No widgets JSON found for the plugin. Please check the documentation on how to add.)

this error seems related to the fact that Data Fusion is trying to use version 1.2.0 (the one already installed) with properties of version 2.2.0.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Update

I can see the two vesions http-plugin from Control Center

[image]

but I cannot set the version

[image]

Problem about http plugin hasn't been solved but I found the existence of pipeline trigger to execute pipeline based on status of another pipeline, this feateure is only available with Enterprise edition.

Comment: What is your Data Fusion version? Did you install httpcallback plugin from [hydrator-plugins](https://github.com/cdapio/hydrator-plugins) repo?

Comment: @mk_sta Yes I installed httpcallback from hydrator-plugins version 2.2.0 and data fusion is version 6.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find `HTTPCallback` post action plugin for the particular batch pipeline attaching appropriate pipeline alert.

Following *Configure* menu from the main dashboard plate:

[image]

Create the new *Alert* object invoking **HTTPCallback** plugin properties list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of the you Data Fusion instance, it may still be defaulting to the old version of the plugin. To select the new version of the plugin you should:

1. Navigate to the Studio
2. Hover your mouse over the HTTP plugin in the sidebar
3. After a second or so, a box will appear with the plugin details. You will see the current version of the plugin and a button beside it that says "Change", click on this button. If you don't see this button that means you only have one version of the plugin in your instance.
   [image]
4. You will see a list of all the versions of the plugin in this instance, select the one you want. The version you select will be the new default version.

You should now be able to use v2.2.0 of the plugin.

Comment: I tried to change version of http-plugin but it's available only version 1.2.0 even if I see also the version 2.2.0 from Control Center. I have integrated the question with screens. Thanks